# Autonumbering Spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet

Good Day,
Im working for a simple orderforms using googlespreadsheet and google forms.
want to ask how create a ordering number which is also have a reset increment when the month is change because the format im using is "year+month" + 1 .
here is the image for your reference im newbie in spreadsheet formulas  Thanks.
[Image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkYG.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,TEXT(B2:B,"yyMM")&TEXT(ROW(B2:B)-VLOOKUP(TEXT(B2:B,"yyyyMM"),{TEXT(B2:B,"yyyyMM"),ROW(B2:B)},2,FALSE)+1,"000")))
```